# Correct Method of Converting Excel Decimal Minutes/Seconds to MM:SS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm tracking my running progress and would like to include my mile pace. My data looks like:

Date    | Miles | Minutes

1/1/20     2.5      30

1/2/20      3       30

And so on. I'm sure there's an easy way to display mile pace in the format "10:00"

The formula I'm using, which works, is:
`=IF(C2/B2<10,LEFT(C2/B2,1),LEFT(C2/B2,2))&":"&ROUND(((C2/B2)-ROUNDDOWN(C2/B2,0))*60,0)`

I think an implementation of `=TEXT(C2/B2,"????)` would return the proper format, just can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change everything to seconds and let TEXT() to handle the conversion:

```
=TEXT(TIME(0,0,C2*60/B2),"mm:ss")
```